# ProgressBar not running smoothly loolipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-appcompat, android-progressbar

I have an indeterminate progress bar that does not run smoothly, the ui thread isn't freezing so probably it's not something that is caused by running a long operaton on ui thread ( I have asynctask ). I am using the latest build tools 22.01 and the target SDK is also 22 and I'm using support library with appcomp. For some reason when the application gets onPause and onResume the progress bar gets back to normal. The devices I test on are nexus 4 and htc1.

videos :

[smooth progressBar >](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2klsjSBLkzHWUpRQjctaFRLT00/view?usp=sharing) 
[not smooth progressBar >](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2klsjSBLkzHOVZGbXh5bnYyUVE&authuser=0)

Comment: Are you using any library for that `ProgressBar` or you are using the default one?

Comment: Maybe it is better you show your code too if we can catch something or it is related with `lollipop`

Comment: i'm only change the visibility  of the view when i need to.

Comment: if you're not running smoothly you're probably doing too much on the UI thread, look for "X frames skipped" logs and fix your code

Comment: Can you show how are you using your async task and where are you creating the progress bar, this is definitely a problem with doing too much work on the UI thread.

Comment: That is so typical in Lollipoop

Answer (score 0):

After I look through the source code of ProgressBar i saw that a setVisibilty and onVisibilityChanged start and stop the animation accordingly

```
public void setVisibility(int v) {
    if (getVisibility() != v) {
        super.setVisibility(v);

        if (mIndeterminate) {
            // let's be nice with the UI thread
            if (v == GONE || v == INVISIBLE) {
                stopAnimation();
            } else {
                startAnimation();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

so i made a call manually 
as follow

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

and this solve the problem ...